# Update multiple records of type radio

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update multiple records of type radio (field "status"). Below is the codes. But as you can see the result here: 
http://lamoncheri.com/admin/dapur.php?id=21
It only recognize the status of one record.

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
  <td align="center"> <input name="nama_menu[]" type="text" id="nama_menu" value="<?php echo $rows['nama_menu']; ?>" readonly style="width: 484px; font-size:medium"> </td>  
  <td align="center"> <input name="qty[]" type="int" id="qty" value="<?php echo $rows['qty']; ?>" readonly style="width: 484px; font-size:medium"> </td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="status[]" id='status' value="order" <?php if ($rows['status'] == "order"){echo "checked";} ?> class ="auto-style5" required>Order<br>
        <input type="radio" name="status[]" id='status' value="process" <?php if ($rows['status'] == "process"){echo "checked";} ?> class ="auto-style5" required>Process<br>
        <input type="radio" name="status[]" id='status' value="finish" <?php if ($rows['status'] == "finish"){echo "checked";} ?> class ="auto-style5" required> Finish<br>
  </td>
  <td style="align:center; color:white"><input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" readonly style="border:0; color:white; width: 10px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Dont add links to your question , Later the links may not be avilable in future

Comment: If you want multiple groups of radio buttons, then you need to use an individual name for each such group - that’s how radio buttons work.

Comment: (And IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score -2):

name put some thing like this

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
  <td align="center"> <input name="nama_menu<?php echo $i; ?>[]" type="text" id="nama_menu" value="<?php echo $rows['nama_menu']; ?>" readonly style="width: 484px; font-size:medium"> </td>  
  <td align="center"> <input name="qty<?php echo $i; ?>[]" type="int" id="qty" value="<?php echo $rows['qty']; ?>" readonly style="width: 484px; font-size:medium"> </td>
  <td> <input type="radio" name="status<?php echo $i; ?>[]" id='status' value="order" <?php if ($rows['status'] == "order"){echo "checked";} ?> class ="auto-style5" required>Order<br>
        <input type="radio" name="status<?php echo $i; ?>[]" id='status' value="process" <?php if ($rows['status'] == "process"){echo "checked";} ?> class ="auto-style5" required>Process<br>
        <input type="radio" name="status<?php echo $i; ?>[]" id='status' value="finish" <?php if ($rows['status'] == "finish"){echo "checked";} ?> class ="auto-style5" required> Finish<br>
  </td>
  <td style="align:center; color:white"><input name="id<?php echo $i; ?>[]" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" readonly style="border:0; color:white; width: 10px"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center">    </td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: This still doesnt update. Am I missing something? With the code I posted, "nama_menu" and "qty"  can be updated. Only "status" does not.

Comment: Replace radio button name & id also 
 name="status[]"  to  name="status<?php echo $i; ?>"

Comment: It still does not update with the code below. What should be modified here:  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
echo $count=count($_POST["id"]);
 
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET status ='" . $_POST['status'][$i] . "' WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'][$i] . "'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}
mysql_close();
?>

Comment: I change it to this. The result is that the status of the first record is empty and the status of the record [i+1] should be the the status of the record [i]. What needs to be corrected? <td> <input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="order"<?php if ($rows['status'] == "order"){echo "checked";} ?> >Order
        <input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="process"<?php if ($rows['status'] == "process"){echo "checked";} ?> >Process